# Integration with partial fractions

Tags: calculus, proof-verification, partial-fractions

$$\int\frac{2}{x(3x-8)}dx=P\cdot \ln\left|x\right|+Q\cdot \ln\left|3x-8\right|$$

Find out what P and Q are equal to.

This is what I worked out:

$$\frac{A}{x}+\frac{B}{3x-8}=\frac{2}{x(3x-8)}$$
$$-\frac{1}{4}=A,\ \ \ \frac{3}{4}=B$$
$$P=A, Q=B$$

why is the answer $P=-\frac{1}{4}, Q=\frac{1}{4}$?

Comment: $B \neq Q$ ... you get a factor of $3$ when you integrate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the integral $\int\dfrac{2}{x(3x-8)}=2\int\dfrac{1}{x(3x-8)}$

Now if you solve $\dfrac{1}{x(3x-8)}$ using partial fractions then you will get
$$\dfrac{1}{x(3x-8)}=\frac{3}{8(3x-8)}-\frac{1}{8x}$$
Now,
$$2\int\dfrac{1}{x(3x-8)}=2\int\frac{3}{8(3x-8)}-\frac{1}{8x}$$
$$=2\left(\frac18\ln|3x-8|-\frac18\ln|x|\right)=\frac14\ln|3x-8|-\frac14\ln|x|$$
Therefore, $P=-\dfrac14$ and $Q=\dfrac14$

**Edit:**
$$2\int\frac{3}{8(3x-8)}dx=\frac34\int\frac{1}{3x-8}dx$$
Apply $u=3x-8$ and we get $$=\frac34\int\frac{1}{3u}=\frac14\int\frac1udu=\frac14\ln|u=\frac14\ln|3x-8|$$

And

$$2\int\frac{1}{8x}=\frac{2}{8}\ln|x|=\frac14\ln|x|$$

Comment: Where did the $3$ go? From $2\int\frac{3}{8(3x-8)}-\int\frac{1}{8x}$ to $=2\left(\frac18\ln|3x-8|-\frac18\ln|x|\right)=\frac14\ln|3x-8|-\frac14\ln|x|$?

Comment: @Jinzu See my edit

Comment: Is your doubt now clarified?

Comment: I see why but do not understand why a u-substitution is done. I did not learn u-substitution with partial fractions integration.

Comment: @Jinzu Because if we have $\int\frac{1}{x-8}$ then it is $\ln|x-8|$. But in this case we have $3x-8$ and you need to take $u$ substitution. We have constant $3$ before $x$

Answer (score 0):

Since $$\frac{{\rm d}(P\cdot \ln\left|x\right|+Q\cdot \ln\left|3x-8\right|)}{{\rm d}x}=\frac{P}{x}+\frac{3Q}{3x-8}=\frac{3(P+Q)x-8P}{x(3x-8)},$$

we obtain $$P+Q=0,~~-8P=2.$$
As a result, $$P=-\frac{1}{4}, ~~~Q=\frac{1}{4}.$$

Comment: Where does $3Q$ come from?

Comment: Do you know the Chain Law？

Comment: $$\frac{{\rm d}\ln |3x-8|}{{\rm d}x}=\frac{{\rm d}\ln |3x-8|}{{\rm d}(3x-8)}\cdot \frac{{\rm d}(3x-8)}{{\rm d}x}=\frac{1}{3x-1}\cdot 3$$